# Where can I read the original One Punch Man

Tags: one-punch-man

Where can I read the original webcomic One Punch Man created by ONE, preferably offline in an iOS app or in printed form.

Comment: Welcome to Anime & Manga! Take note that this site doesn't condone piracy, so we will only mention legal/official sites if they exist. Answers/comments that mention questionable sites will be removed without prompt.

Comment: That said, are you looking for the English translation or the original Japanese?

Comment: I’d prefer Japanese but if it exist in English I’d like that also. I am also only interested in legal sources and it is OK if it costs money.

Answer (score 5):

The web-comic of One Punch Man is a self-published work by ONE, and are freely available, in Japanese, on [their website](http://galaxyheavyblow.web.fc2.com/)

As far as I know there are no printed or digital versions available for purchase. Hence for offline reading I would suggest a app/browser that supports offline reading.

Answer (score 2):

Well, since you're apparently limited to iOS, and PC, I advise downloading all of [the webcomic](http://galaxyheavyblow.web.fc2.com/)
to your computer and reading it at your own pace.